# CakePHP 3 - Warning shown due to length of content?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've got a strange problem whereby I'm seeing the following PHP Warnings:

```
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php line=921 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Code Context
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 105
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:921) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 148]
Code Context
header - [internal], line ??
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emitStatusLine() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 148
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 54
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 105
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:921) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
Code Context
header - [internal], line ??
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emitHeaders() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 55
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 105
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

I'm in development mode (`'DEBUG', true` in `app/config.php`). If I set that to `false` the Warnings disappear, as expected.

The error is originating from this Controller method:

```
public function ajaxSubstances()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $SubstanceModel = new SubstanceModel;
    $data = ['data' => $SubstanceModel->getSubstances()];
    debug($data);
}
```

What I don't understand is that if my `$data` array only contains, say 20 elements, no Warning is shown. As I gradually add more elements it always shows the Warning once there is a certain number of records (approx >=30 elements).

To check it's not the source data (from `getSubstances()`) I hardcoded a `$data` array in, but the same thing happens.

This method will be used as an ajax response and be fed into DataTables. Unfortunately if the Warnings are output, DataTables will show an error because it's not a valid response.

I can't switch `debug` to `false` because I need to have that on for the rest of my development. And I'd like to know why this may be happening anyway?

I'm not sure why it's trying to "emit headers" because the header type isn't being changed anywhere in the code - it's outputting everything using `debug()`, and I also tried `var_dump()` but the output is still the same `text/html` content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily due to the length of the content, but generally due to outputting data before the emitter can output headers, it will happen once there's even a single byte being sent before the response emitter comes into play, which explicitly tests for `headers_sent()`.

Note that there are further headers that may need to be emitted besides those that you might have applied to the response yourself, like cookies, content length, etc.

You most probably only see the warning as of a certain amount of data because you're using PHPs output buffering and/or compression (see `output_buffering` and `zlib.output_compression` in your `php.ini`), which will only automatically flush data in the midst of the script in case the buffer storage capabilities are being exceeded (in most cases that's usually 4096 bytes).

See also

- **http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php**
- **http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php**

Comment: Thanks as always for your help. The data I needed to output needed to be a JSON feed. I configured JSON views as described in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html and that seems to have helped - the content-type headers are set appropriately and I can output any amount of data without issues, or so it seems this far!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using **JavaScript**, when receiving ajax call response on the client side instead of **response["responsText"]** use **["responseJSON"]**.

Calling *JSON.parse(response["responseText"])* would fail because in cakePHP debug mode  a warning/error in html is appended before the actual json result within **"responsText"** when the result is too long.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/projects/someMethod",
        async: true,
        data: requestParams,
        complete: function (resp) {
            try {
                //instead of var = JSON.parse(resp["responseText"]) use 
                var responseData = resp["responseJSON"];
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    });
```

On cakePHP'server side you can have **someMethod** implemented like this (without the need of creating a view):

```
public function someMethod()
{
    if($this->request->is('ajax'))
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        //some $returnData  assigment

        $this->response->body(json_encode($returnData));
        $this->response->type('json');

        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put off debug statement if you have put. because server considers it echo and display messages which results in headers already sent error in lower versions of php like php7.0

Comment: If you start an answer with "try" there is a great chance it's not an answer, but actually a question for clarification in disguise. Wait until you have comment privilege to post something like this in a comment, and once you know that your suggestion is a viable solution, post it as an answer that says "do the thing. it works because" not "try the thing. maybe it works because"

Comment: Furthermore, it was already answered 2 years ago. The accepted answer was accepted because it, erm, works.